# Getting a NoSuchElementException 33

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I don't know why I am getting this error. What should I do to fix it? Any help really appreciated. I excluded code that does not affect the error. Line 33 is String string1 = token.nextToken();

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exec {
public static void main(String[ ] args){


        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        String user_input = " ";

        //user gets asked to enter input here...
                    //...

        //tokenize input into 2 strings and method code
        user_input = input.next( );
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(user_input);
        String string0 = token.nextToken();
        String string1 = token.nextToken();
        code = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
```

Answer (score 3):

You've run out of tokens. You should print out your String before tokenizing it as it is likely not be what you think it is. In other words what you want to do now is some debugging.

- Note 1: always check first if more tokens exist with `hasMoreTokens()` before taking a token with `nextToken()`.
- Note 2: most of us avoid use of StringTokenizer and instead use either a Scanner or `String#split(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have as many tokens in `user_input` as you think you do. By default, 
[`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) reads up to the next whitespace character and StringTokenizer uses a smaller subset of whitespace characters as the delimiter, as stated in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Maybe you should read user input using `Scanner#nextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hasMoreTokens() method while traversing using StringTokenizer to check that tokens are actually present.This method call returns 'true' if and only if there is at least one token in the string after the current position;

```
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(user_input);

// checking tokens

while (token.hasMoreTokens()){

     System.out.println("Next token : " + token.nextToken());
     }
```

Also,in your code you are calling nextToken 3 times,so 3 tokens will be traversed.So, if your input string has less than 3 tokens it would fail with the exception you are getting.

It looks like you want to convert one of the tokens to integer in the call 
    code = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());

do you want to say  "code = Integer.parseInt(string1)" OR "code = Integer.parseInt(string2)" instead?

Because when you say token.nextToken in integer.parseInt it would again look for next token i.e. 3rd token in this case.hope this helps.

Comment: This looks very helpful to me. 1+